# Publish iOS app using MDM solution

Tags: ios, mdm, enterprise-distribution

We have Apple's Enterprise distribution account that we are using to publish enterprise app to company employees. We are using MDM solution for distribution.
Do we need to generate ipa for MDM deployment differently than the standard App store procedure? obviously we have selected Enterprise deployment at end using xcode's generate ipa method.

How all devices in the company can install app using MDM. Do we need to prepare devices somehow first?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which MDM service provider did you use?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out so writing a reply
One has to generate "Enterprise Provisioning" profile replicating App store one. You have not to include any devices in the Provisioning profile. Everything will be managed by MDM.